# do not apply as.double to all row when spesific condition is given

Tags: r, dplyr

I have table like this

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | one | tax | value |
| 2 | two | 0.5 | 100 |
| 3 | three | tax | value |
| 4 | four | 0.7 | 200 |

I want create new column E from C * D

All column data type is character
I try this code

```
newTable <- table %>% 
  mutate(E = "") %>%
   mutate(E = ifelse(row_number() %in% c(2, 4), as.double(C) * as.double(D), E)
```

but there Warning Message: NAs Introduced by Coercion. How i can achive this with dplyr and without warning and not set warning off

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are looking for a dplyr-specific answer. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the meaning of [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) in `tidyverse`. If you transform your data accordingly the steps become much easier to implement. Currently columns contain both variable names and values, different data structures.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble::tribble(
  ~A,      ~B,    ~C,      ~D,
  1L,   "one", "tax", "value",
  2L,   "two", "0.5",   "100",
  3L, "three", "tax", "value",
  4L,  "four", "0.7",   "200"
  )

split(df, c(T, F))[[1]] %>% # get only values of interest
  mutate(across(3:4, as.numeric),
         E = C*D) %>%
  rename("tax" = C, "value" = D) # reinstate the variable information

# A tibble: 2 x 5
      A B       tax value     E
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2 two     0.5   100    50
2     4 four    0.7   200   140
```